# Unable to install the package flameshot

Tags: screenshot

Just trying to install flameshot, lightshot doesnt work

And I get this:

```
sudo apt install flameshot

Reading package list ... Done 
Creating dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done 
E: The flameshot package could not be located
```

Can someone please explain to me how to figure out this issue .

Comment: You should insert questions in english

Comment: Be sure to perform sudo apt-get update.

Comment: tried all and still not work

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?  flameshot is only available for Bionic 18.04 and newer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 2):

In order to install `flameshot` on [Ubuntu 18.04 or newer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=flameshot&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), you need to have the Universe repository enabled.

Run the following commands to enable the Universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

Now, install flameshot:

```
sudo apt install flameshot
```

You can find information about which repository provides a package and the availability of packages in different distro versions by visiting [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com)